# LazyLoad FireFox Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I'm trying to use the following lazyload plugin but for some reason it doesn't work in Firefox

https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var lazyloader = new LazyLoad();
    });
```

Everything works as expected in chrome but in FF I receive the following error(s)

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: LazyLoad is not defined
ReferenceError: LazyLoad is not defined
```

has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: did you try using the jQuery wrapper plugin shown in docs?

Comment: I have, I also notice the following demo page doesn't appear to work in FF. https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled/

Comment: It looks like your LazyLoad is not yet loaded when the time of calling it. Make it sure the lazyload script is served "synchronously" and before the main script.